# Adding a value to a SUM

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have a row with multiple blank values.  I want the answer to be `""` if all values are blank.  If any of the cells contain a value, I would like to take the `SUM` of those cells, and add 10 to it.  The formula I am using is below, and it always displays the answer as `"10"`, even if all cells are blank.  Please help.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1:D1),"",SUM(A1:D1)+10)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the cells **are** blank. A cell that contains "" is **not** blank.

Answer (score 1):

`ISBLANK()` only works on a single cell. You want to use `COUNTA()` instead.

> Counts the number of cells in a range that are not empty

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:D1) = 0,"",SUM(A1:D1)+10)
```